# c# resetting progress bar while reading 2 or more tables from database

Tags: c#

so in my simple program, i have one progress bar and one button.

now this button will read 2 tables from my database (`mysql` as an example).

Just 2 simple select statements for reading 2 different tables.

**My Question is**

how can I implement the progress bar such that after it reads/selects the first table, the progress bar value will reset to 0 and continue on reading the next table and also increment again the progress bar?

This functionality is very similar when installing some applications, where every file to copy has separate progress but is using only one progress bar.

If you could provide examples it would be helpful.

Much better if you could provide with backgroundworker as well

Comment: you should add some examples of what you have tried so far and why it didn't work as expected. This is MSDN article on implementing backgroud workers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: The way the progress bar works in MSI is rather a major UI blooper, not something anybody ever should try to copy.  Use marquee style progress if you don't know how many records are in the result sets.

Answer (score 0):

You will have an idea:
If you have questions, please let me know.

```
async private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteSQL1);
            UpdateProgressBar(0);
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteSQL2);
            UpdateProgressBar(0);            
        }

private void ExecuteSQL1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int progressBarValue = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateProgressBar(progressBarValue), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

 private void ExecuteSQL2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {   
                int progressBarValue = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateProgressBar(progressBarValue), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

TaskScheduler uiScheduler;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1). When reading database you don't know how many entries you will receive to get the exact progress. So you need this information from the SQL server. Please, read [Report progress from SQL Server](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/20/11431.aspx).

2). How to use the `BackgroundWorker` is explained very good in DEV N00B's comment. To execute two queries I would create a separate worker with its own DoWork-function for each query and call them this way

```
private void worker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  this.progressBar1.Value = 0;

  Thread.Sleep(1000);

  if (worker2.IsBusy != true)
  {
    worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
}
```